# Magento 2: file_get_contents and curl not working on server

Tags: magento2, php, curl

`file_get_contents` and curl not working on server but working well in local.

And also `allow_url_fopen = On`.

```
$b1 = "https://www.demo.com/";

$response = file_get_contents($b1);
print_r(json_decode($response,true));
```

How to fix to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have curl active on your php.ini. if so, please try to access your webservice via postman and let me know what is the error it is giving.